# Move UITextField above keyboard when user click on textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I want to move `UITextField` up above keyboard when user clicks `UITextField`.

I searched about this and some suggestion are to move whole view up and some suggestion are add scrollview.

But I don't want to use scrollview.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Move the textfield, move the whole view which contains the textfield or use scrollView. If you don't want to use `UIScrollView`, just move the view or the view containing the textfield. Not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `UITextField` bottom Constant and when you found keyboard height in `keyboardWillShow` increase your `UITextField` bottom constraint to `KeyboardHeight`.

**Just Put below code in ViewWillAppear.**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

**And put below code in ViewWillDisappear.**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                  object:nil];
```

**Method**

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    int keyboardHeight = MIN(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);

    textBottom.constant = 0.0f;

    for (UIView *vw in commentView.subviews) {
        if ([vw isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            txtComment = (UITextField *)vw;
            textBottom.constant = keyboardHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one awesome solution:
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

It easy to integrate and effortless.

You won't have to use a UIScrollView in each of your UIViewControllers.

Comment: I don't want to use IQKeyboardManager.